# Android installation

Tags: android, android-ndk, installation

I am newbie to android. I wanted to learn android programming. SO i downloaded . I have installed software successfully. Since i dont have device with Me. I wanted to run on emulator.But i can't use emulator Here. Please let me Know What are SDK package to be installed. When enviorment It comes up with SDK package & SDK manager.exe. How can install These package. If click on SDK manager : it again try to download & installed. 
Wheater i need to download or install packages directly .

[image: SDK manager][image: SDK packages][image: AVD]

I am using Windows XP ; 32 bit

[Android Enviorment esciplse](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) 
&
[NDK](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

As I see in screenshot .You have not installed system image for API-20.You have installed system image for API 21.Please select target system image of API 21.Otherwise,

If you want to run app on emulator with fast speed,Try [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com) -
It is better than a android emulator.
You can download a version for Windows after registering.

Comment: what i need to install system image for API-20

Comment: You should download Android 4.4.2(API 19) :- SDK Platform and ARM System Image or Intel System Image

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, you downloaded system images from API-21 but you are trying to create an AVD with API-20.

No, for API-20, "No system image available for this target" is a correct behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Wait for the android sdk manager to load all the packages and it will let you know how many packages have to be updated/installed/deleted. All you need to do is select Intel HAXM emulator accelerator which will not be selected by default and it is highly recommended that you install all the packages suggested in the sdk manager